# Aggregating covariances

Tags: covariance, large-data

Suppose I have 2 data sets too large to combine.

Each data set has one row per user, $i$, and two columns $(x, y)$. Users can be in both data sets but have different column values, $(x_{i1}, y_{i1})$ & $(x_{i2}, y_{i2})$.

I want to calculate the covariance between $x  = (x_{i1} + x_{i2})$ & $y = (y_{i1} + y_{i2})$.

Is there a good way to approximate this based on the summary statistics (such as mean, variance and covariance) of each data set?

Comment: To calculate the sum $x_{i1}+x_{i2}$ and so on, the user $i$ must be in both datasets.  Are you interested only in those cases, if so, can you filter away the users which are not duplicated? If not it is very unclear what you want. Can you please clarify?